# How to validate fields read from a text file in python

Tags: python, validation, text-files

I'm hoping someone can help (I'm new to python). I have created a text file with customer information.

The details that are being stored in the text file are "First Name, Last name, Telephone Number, and email address".

I wish to create a python program to read the file. However, before adding information from the file, I want to do validation checks.

How do I get Python to do a validation check on the data e.g. data entered is the correct data type?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check data in Python.  What are you trying to validate?